# How can i separate CustomerName and CustomerPhone from this string which i am recieving from api

Tags: java, android

How can I separate CustomerName and CustomerPhone from this string which I am receiving from API:

```
{
  "CustomerPhone":"0300",
  "CustomerName":"Saleh",
  "CustomerPassword":"84CYmCulToJXo5KncGwSZa81acb2vbHjZ2IgUveMyeU=",
  "Salt":"Q/IoQURM1Cv05wbkJjuo3w=="
}
```

Comment: That is a JSON string. You should find a library that can help you parse JSON data. Hint, check out Jackson or GSON libraries

Comment: i want this "Saleh" and "0300" separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
String jsonText = "{\"CustomerPhone\":\"0300\",\"CustomerName\":\"Saleh\",\"CustomerPassword\":\"84CYmCulToJXo5KncGwSZa81acb2vbHjZ2IgUveMyeU=\",\"Salt\":\"Q/IoQURM1Cv05wbkJjuo3w==\"}";
try {
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonText);
    String CustomerPhone = jsonObj.getString("CustomerPhone");
    String CustomerName = jsonObj.getString("CustomerName");
} catch (JSONException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: this is showing string cannot be converted into jsonobject

Comment: I have my Android Studio open and I've tested it before posting the code and was working fine. I think that you probably have some special (unwanted) characters on your string. Have you tested my code with my "string" as it is? or are you using yours?

Comment: boss when i tried your code it work fine but it is not working on the json string which is coming from web api in this form plz help

"{\"CustomerPhone\":\"0300\",\"CustomerName\":\"Saleh\",\"CustomerPassword\":\"84CYmCulToJXo5KncGwSZa81acb2vbHjZ2IgUveMyeU=\",\"Salt\":\"Q/IoQURM1Cv05wbkJjuo3w==\"}"

Comment: it is coming in a variable of string

Comment: Thanks for your help i have solved it by this :

  String a = s.replaceAll("\\\\\"", "\"");
                                String b = a.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");
                                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(b);
                                String CustomerPhone = jObj.getString("CustomerPhone");
                                String CustomerName = jObj.getString("CustomerName");

where s is incoming string

Answer (score 1):

Below are the very easy steps to get it done,

Step 1: Go to http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ and paste your JSON, now select options Target language as Java, Source Type JSON , Annotation Style GSON. And press preview button, and copy model to clipboard.

Step 2: Now in your project Add GSON library

Step 3: Create Model Class with name CustomerData or anything you want, and paste code from clipboard.

It will look alike

```
public class CustomerData {

@SerializedName("CustomerPhone")
@Expose
private String customerPhone;
@SerializedName("CustomerName")
@Expose
private String customerName;
@SerializedName("CustomerPassword")
@Expose
private String customerPassword;
@SerializedName("Salt")
@Expose
private String salt;

public String getCustomerPhone() {
return customerPhone;
}

public void setCustomerPhone(String customerPhone) {
this.customerPhone = customerPhone;
}

public String getCustomerName() {
return customerName;
}

public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
this.customerName = customerName;
}

public String getCustomerPassword() {
return customerPassword;
}

public void setCustomerPassword(String customerPassword) {
this.customerPassword = customerPassword;
}

public String getSalt() {
return salt;
}

public void setSalt(String salt) {
this.salt = salt;
}

}
```

Step 4: 
Now you have to parse your JSON to GSON Object by following code, where **response** variable will be your JSON string.

```
CustomerData customerData = new Gson().fromJson(response,CustomerData.class);
customerData.getCustomerName();
customerData.getCustomerPhone();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options.

1. Use a simple JSON library like GSON and create a model that you simply convert the string into and you're done
2. Use the Android JsonElements and create a JsonElement from the string and walk each child by name until you get the ones you need.
3. Ugliest way but you can do it, parse the string by known strings. (not tested, you would have to tweak this, but I really hope you don't go this route lol)

> var customerStartPhoneIndex = jsonString.indexOf("CustomerPhone\":\")
>
> var customerStartNameIndex = jsonString.indexOf("CustomerName\":\")
>
> var customerEndphoneIndex = jsonString.indexOf(",")
>
> var customerEndNameIndex = jsonString.indexOf(",", str.indexOf(",") +
>   1)
>
> var customerPhone = jsonString.subString(customerStartPhoneIndex,
>   customerEndPhoneIndex)
>
> var customerName = jsonString.substring(customerStartNameIndex,
>   customerEndNameIndex)

Answer (score 0):

For your given String the below code will work fine, I have tested and it is pretty self explaining.

```
    val jsonObject = JSONObject(jsonString)
    val phone = jsonObject.getString("CustomerPhone")
    val name = jsonObject.getString("CustomerName")
    val password = jsonObject.getString("CustomerPassword")
    val salt = jsonObject.getString("Salt")

    Log.d("phone", phone)
    Log.d("name", name)
    Log.d("password", password)
    Log.d("salt", salt)
```

Hope this helps thank You